# How do I use pen tool to connect lines of constellation dots in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pen-tool

How do I use pen tool to connect lines of constellation dots in photoshop? I tried to do this by using pen tool. But once I hit enter, the lines disappear. I tried shift, alt, ctrl but they don't seem to work. I watched some YouTube videos but most of them are about how to use pen tool for drawing shapes not lines. Would appreciate help. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like your using the pen tool wrong. There should be no need to hit enter. Also, the LINE tool is probably better suited to connecting dots with straight lines.

Answer (score 3):

You can in fact use the Pen tool to achieve what you need just by making sure you select **Shape** tool mode instead of **Path** from the top-left dropdown [for the tool mode dropdown to be shown you need to have the pen tool selected].

Also, be sure to select a stroke color and width. After you have finished connecting all the dots, press enter.

[image]

Comment: I tried using Shape but instead of lines to connect constellation of stars, it's creating a shape inside with the default color I am using, which is white. So it's actually creating a shape and covering it up with white color. Looked for a transparent color but could not find it. Can I just do a line that connects dots of stars?